# Plot with for loop from different datasets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, plot

I have 2 datasets:

df1=

```
    id_first    latitude    longitude
0   403         45.0714     7.6187
1   403         45.0739     7.6195
2   1249        45.0745     7.6152
3   1249        45.1067     7.6451
4   1249        45.1062     7.6482
5   1531        45.1088     7.6528
6   1531        45.1005     7.6155
7   14318       45.1047     7.6056
```

df2 =

```
    id_now  cluster_group
0   403     0
1   1249    1
2   1531    3
3   14318   3
```

I want can not create a loop (or smth else) to:

- in `df2` Value `403` belong to only one cluster_group `(0)` go to `df1` and
  check all point related to `403` latitude - 2 points and longitude - 2
  points. And plot them.
- repeat to the whole df1 df2 bu plotting in one graph (different colors for every cluster) - I can manage this actually, but if you can offer smth (?)

P.S. in `df2` `1531` and `14318` belongs to the same cluster. So anyway, I want to plot its points in one color (or one map).

Try:

```
n_clusters = 46

for k in range(0, n_clusters):
     ....
```

[image: plot sample]

Every color represents `cluster_group`

Comment: If you already have a solution... what's your current solution and why are you looking for an alternative? If you explain these points, you can hope for a better answer.

Comment: @Valentino I don’t have solution. It’s a random photo from internet

Comment: Ah, ok. Because you said "i can manage this" so I thought you had a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using `pandas` and `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#here I read the dataframe from a file, you read it in the way you prefer
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('data2.txt', sep='\s+')

#the important piece of code is here:
for g, gdf in df2.groupby('cluster_group'):
    df1_to_plot = df1.loc[df1['id_first'].isin(gdf['id_now'])]
    plt.plot(df1_to_plot['latitude'], df1_to_plot['longitude'], label='Cluster {:d}'.format(g))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Some explanation if you are not familiar with [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

1. `df2.groupby('cluster_group')` return an iterator over subsets of `df2`, each subset is buildt grouping all the rows with the same value in `'cluster_group'` column.
2. Using each of these subsets `gdf` I select the rows of `df1` where the value in column `'id_first'` is contained in `gdf`. This is done by `isin` method. This selection is stored in the dataframe `df1_to_plot`, which contains the data to be plotted.
3. Now I can use `plt.plot` to actually plot the data. Matplotlib will take care of the color by itself. The `label` parameter is used by the `legend` method when creating the legend.

Using the simple data you provided, this code would produce the following image (x axis is latitude, y axis is longitude:

[image: sample plot]